# My app.component.html is not showing in my Angular app

Tags: angular

my app.component.html looks like this

```
\<div>abcd</div>
```

and my app.component.ts    look like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'LoginApp';
 }
```

and my index.html    looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>LoginApp</title>
 <base href="/">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a very simple code. I am not understanding where is the problem...Can anybody help?
If I add any text in the index.html then it is being shown in the browser

Comment: Did you create your project using the `ng new` command or manually??

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

If you have the slashes this will cause errors:

in your app.component.html file try this:

```
<div style="display: flex; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; justify-content: center; color: #333"><h1>hello</h1></div>
```